# Is there a standard design pattern for dealing with views that have both read and write states?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

I'm wondering if there are any standard design patterns employed by the Backbone (and similar) community as a whole which reflect a "best practice" for readability and design with respect to view components that not only presents data to the end-user but also allows for editing their contents. A user would toggle between the read-and-write presentations by interacting with a link, or button. A good example of the type of behavior I'm thinking of is the Stack Overflow Career's site which permits you to edit your entries and switches between read-and-write contexts.

As I see if there are two approaches:

1. Create a template which includes the read-only data as well as the `<form>` in a single template and wire up the show/hide functionality.
2. Create **two separate** views, one for the read-only data and the other for the `<form>`, and render both independently.

Are there others? Is there a preference that has emerged with in the community on how this design pattern should be approached?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, it might be possible to go for a read-only view which allows the user to click on/hover over the text values, which make them turn into an editable textbox/checkbox/radiobutton... The label would be a read only textbox, styled so that it doesn't look like a textbox. This enables you to easily switch states by swapping classes... This way there is no need to switch modes (edit/view) for the entire view. Savind can be done on textvaluechanges, or when a button is pressed. It might be not useful for u, but just my 2cents!

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change something on presentation layer you should definitely change model (on some events for example). It can be manager at your View. For example:

```
    vare View = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'panel-body',

    template: 'datalibrary/dl-upload-form-file-view',

    events: {
        'change .someSelector': 'someHandler'
    },

    initialize : function(){
       this.listenTo(this.model,'change','modelChangehalder') 
    }

    someHandler: function(e){
       // update model here
    },

    modelChangehalder : function() {
       // some updates on model change
    }
```

Once you have your state i your model you can play around as you wan't and perist it to the server, save to storage or whatever you want.

Also take a look at the [Backbone.Controller](https://github.com/artyomtrityak/backbone.controller) project. 
It allows to add C to Backbones MV* pattern. In this case you will be able to manage your view-model relations inside controller, in my opinion it's better approach.

Comment: Agreed that it should be managed by the view, but it isn't clear to me how this addresses the question above which is: "If I have a view that has both read (e.g. display) and write (e.g. form) components to it should this be one view or two?" It sounds like you're advocating for a single view?